# Why do the Galois and Hecke action commute on the Picard group of the modular curve $X_1(N)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modular-forms, galois-representations

In chapter 9 of Diamond-Shurman's book *A First Course in Modular Forms*, when they construct the Tate module associated to the modular curve $X_1(N)$, they state that the Galois action and Hecke action on the Picard group $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X_1(N))$ commute (on page 387).

While I understand why Hecke operators commute with Hecke operators, why would a Hecke operator commute with an element of the Galois group? In other words, for $T\in\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$, why does
\begin{equation}
\sigma(T(x))=T(\sigma(x))
\end{equation}
for all $x\in\mathrm{Pic}^0(X_1(N))$? A priori, the Galois group is noncommutative, so $\sigma\sigma'\ne\sigma'\sigma$ for all $\sigma,\sigma'\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. I feel like I'm missing something basic about group actions or (Galois) modules, but I can't see what.

Comment: Can you explain a bit how Hecke operators are defined? Sometimes aree defined as correspondences using the maps $X_1(NM)\to X_1(N)$, which are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, so they are Galois equivariant.

Comment: Oooooooh, they are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, so they *are* Galois equivariant. Thank you!

Comment: The two maps $X_1(NM)\to X_1(N)$ are maps that "forget" structure in the moduli interpretation; they are defined when the moduli interpretation works...